# Are there any radiation emitted from the cameras?

Tags: radiation, electronics, camera

Do modern video cameras emit any kind of radiation? If so, what range of frequencies they have? I was wondering if we can detect any radiation so any help regarding detection will also be appreciated.

Comment: All electrical equipment radiates some electromagnetic waves. Can you be a bit more precise about what you think a video camera might be radiating and why?

Comment: Most bodies will emmit infrared radiation.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum. I'll edit this.

Comment: @JohnRennie : First of all, I am doing a final year project that will detect those radiations. So I am trying to find out if we can measure any type of radiation that is emitted from video cameras. I read that they produce we can detect the clock frequency produced with the help of spectrum analysis. Eg. Emissions of a tested CCD camera were noted, and the clock frequency peak was at 18.96 Mhz and its harmonics at 37.9 MHz, 56.8 MHz, 75.8 MHz and 94.7 Mhz. Also they emit thermal radiation by heating of electronic components. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, the answer is negligibly so. Video cameras now digitise the image as pixels in parallel using [charge coupled device technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device). Former technologies, however, would emit appreciable bremstrahlung from decelerating electron beams, as I now describe.

Before the coming of CCD arrays, the main video technology was the [scanned photocathode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photocathode), also called the "vidicon" and "orthicon" (I think these words were trade names), where a scanning electron beam polled the amount of charge that had been displaced by the photoelectric effect. A lens system focussed the image onto the photocathode: whenever the scanning beam swept through a regoin that had been exposed to a bright light, part of the beam would be drained to replace the dislodged charge and the flow of extra current needed to do this could be registered. Thus, as the beam scanned, the amount of photoelectrically dislodged charge as a function of position can be plotted to form an image.

Since this technology involves a scanning electron beam that is sharply decelerated at the photocathode, the radiation emissions are considerably more than from modern CCD devices. Typical bremstrahlung emitted by the collision of 10keV electrons with various materials are detailed in the paper

[Gustavo Castellano , Janos Osan ,Jorge Trincavelli, "Analytical model for the bremsstrahlung spectrum in the 0.25–20 keV photon energy range", Spectrochimica Acta Part B 59 (2004) 313–319](http://www.famaf.unc.edu.ar/~gcas/papers/sab04.pdf)

This is a good indication of what radiations from a 20kV image orthicon would be like: *i.e.* soft X-rays of up to a few keV energy (with representative frequency given by $1000 q/h=2\times 10^{17}{\rm Hz}$. How intense these emissions are depends on the shielding around the orthicon.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But is there any research paper regarding the emissions from modern cameras? I actually want to know what exactly they emit no matter how negligible they are.

Comment: @Decoder: I would be surprised if anybody were willing to spend the money on such an expensive measurement. Manufacturers only test for compliance against FCC regulations with regards to EMC (electromagnetic compatibility). Nobody on the product level will test for e.g. ionizing radiation when there is no known ionizing radiation source in the design.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Actually, I am doing a final year project that will detect those radiations. So I am trying to find out if we can measure any type of radiation that is emitted from video cameras. I read that we can detect the clock frequency produced by them with the help of spectrum analysis. Eg. Emissions of a tested CCD camera were noted, and the clock frequency peak was at 18.96 Mhz and its harmonics at 37.9 MHz, 56.8 MHz, 75.8 MHz and 94.7 Mhz. We can also detect line frequency of the video signal which is in the range of approx 15 kHz.

Comment: Also they emit thermal radiation by heating of electronic components. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Decoder: That's all boring electronics EMC and has very little to do with what physicist mean by "radiation". All you need to see those is a spectrum analyzer and a few antennas. Why is that of interest? And thermal radiation? Every human is emitting plenty of that. Why bother? You are also a radioactive source  for x-ray lines of Pptassium 40. The joke among nuclear physicists is, that the largest natural source of radioactivity in your life is your wife/hubby.

Comment: @CuriousOne I've not heard this one before, but I think I'm going to tell Mindy (Mrs Savanna Animal) this.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: About the 40 K? :-) Careful with whose bones you sleep/dance/cuddle... they are all 'hot'!

Comment: Yes it would be boring enough, I understand. But told about the project part. So can you suggest any type of research paper on this field?